# Counting clicked Images that have moved javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, count

I need to count images that have been clicked however many times they are clicked and displayed in an alert.

I can get this to work, however, I am rotating the images in a table which means it is only counting the space where the images are and not the image themselves.

I am not sure how to make the image be counted instead of just the array value/space.

```
   <html>
   <head>
    <script>
   count = [0, 0, 0, 0]
   function myAlert(n)
       {

       count[n]++

           alert(document.images[n].src + " " + count[n])
       }

   function rotImage()
       {
       document.getElementById('pic1').src = 
   "C:/Users/Cain/Documents/School/College/Junior 2/Cancerscript/tablepic3.png"
       document.getElementById('pic2').src = 
   "C:/Users/Cain/Documents/School/College/Junior 2/Cancerscript/tablepic1.png"
       document.getElementById('pic3').src = 
   "C:/Users/Cain/Documents/School/College/Junior 2/Cancerscript/tablepic4.png"
       document.getElementById('pic4').src = 
   "C:/Users/Cain/Documents/School/College/Junior 2/Cancerscript/tablepic2.png"
       }


    </script>
   </head>

   <body>
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
     <tr>
      <td>
       <img src="C:\Users\Cain\Documents\School\College\Junior 
   2\Cancerscript\tablepic1.png"
       width="200" height="200" id="pic1" onclick = "myAlert(0)">
      </td>
      <td>
       <img src="C:\Users\Cain\Documents\School\College\Junior 
   2\Cancerscript\tablepic2.png"
       width="200" height="200" id="pic2" onclick = "myAlert(1)">
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
       <img src="C:\Users\Cain\Documents\School\College\Junior 
   2\Cancerscript\tablepic3.png"
       width="200" height="200" id="pic3" onclick = "myAlert(2)">
      </td>
      <td>
       <img src="C:\Users\Cain\Documents\School\College\Junior 
    2\Cancerscript\tablepic4.png"
       width="200" height="200" id="pic4" onclick = "myAlert(3)">
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    <input type = "button" value = "Rotate" onclick = "rotImage()">
   </body>

   </html>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When presented with something like this, it's helpful to think about what's unique to the image itself? In this case, it's the file name itself.

Go by the source of the image rather than the index. This code creates an object whose property names are the file names of the images in question. The values are the number of times that image has been clicked.

Then, in the event handlers, I pass the source of the clicked-upon image. Then I go through the property names, find the one that matches the file name, and increment it. Then alert the newly updated count.

Note that there is a way of doing this without the loop, but I'll leave that exercise for you to figure out.

```js
var count = {
  "tablepic1.png": 0,
  "tablepic2.png": 0,
  "tablepic3.png": 0,
  "tablepic4.png": 0
};

function myAlert(src) {
  var keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(count);
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var key = keys[i];
    if (src.indexOf(key) > -1) {
      count[key]++;
      alert(src + " " + count[key]);
    }
  }
}

function rotImage() {
  document.getElementById('pic1').src =
    "C:/Users/Cain/Documents/School/College/Junior 2/Cancerscript/tablepic3.png"
  document.getElementById('pic2').src =
    "C:/Users/Cain/Documents/School/College/Junior 2/Cancerscript/tablepic1.png"
  document.getElementById('pic3').src =
    "C:/Users/Cain/Documents/School/College/Junior 2/Cancerscript/tablepic4.png"
  document.getElementById('pic4').src =
    "C:/Users/Cain/Documents/School/College/Junior 2/Cancerscript/tablepic2.png"
}
```

```html
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="C:\Users\Cain\Documents\School\College\Junior 
   2\Cancerscript\tablepic1.png" width="200" height="200" id="pic1" onclick="myAlert(this.src)">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="C:\Users\Cain\Documents\School\College\Junior 
   2\Cancerscript\tablepic2.png" width="200" height="200" id="pic2" onclick="myAlert(this.src)">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="C:\Users\Cain\Documents\School\College\Junior 
   2\Cancerscript\tablepic3.png" width="200" height="200" id="pic3" onclick="myAlert(this.src)">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="C:\Users\Cain\Documents\School\College\Junior 
    2\Cancerscript\tablepic4.png" width="200" height="200" id="pic4" onclick="myAlert(this.src)">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Rotate" onclick="rotImage()">
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not realize you could declare arrays like that. This helps a ton!